# jQuery failed to load the given url

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to create a jQuery lightbox and while doing this I was trying to create a image with jQuery and append it to the dom i got an error thats shown in firebug : Failed to load the give URL.

I've checked double checked and triple checked the url of the image is corect furthermore i'm using phpstorm as my IDE and it highliths my code if the path dosent exist.This is my jQuery code:

```
$('<div></div>').addClass('bg-lightbox')
                   .fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        var width = $(window).width() / 2 - ($('div.lightbox').width() / 2);
                        var height = $(window).height()/2 - ($('div.lightbox').height() / 2);
           console.log(width);

                        $('<div></div>').addClass('lightbox')
                                        .css({
                                            'left':width,
                                            'top':height

                                        })
                                        .animate({
                                            'width':'+=600px',
                                            'height':'+=400px',
                                            'left':'-=300px',
                                            'top':'-=200px'
                                         }, 'slow' , 'easeInQuad')
                                        .appendTo('body');
                        $('<div></div>').addClass('exit')
                                        .appendTo('div.lightbox');
                        console.log('Image Start');
                        $('<img src="../img/X.png" alt="Close">').addClass('x')
                                                                          .fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                                                            console.log('Its done');
                                                                          })
                                                                          .appendTo('div.exit');
                    })
                   .appendTo('body');
});
```

And this is the css that styles it:

```
    div.bg-lightbox{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 300;
}
div.lightbox{
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 400;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #DFE2E8;
    border:3px solid #677EA1;
}

    div.exit{
        width:5%;
        height: 6%;
        position: absolute;
        top:-15px;
        right:-15px;
        z-index: 500;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #DFE2E8;
        border:3px solid #677EA1;

    }
        img.x{
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            z-index: 600;
        }
```

It's probably a beginner mistake.Thanx in advance!

**EDIT**:Also it seems that the lightbox loads extremly slow in chrome oposed to firefox those anyone has an answey why this hapens?

Comment: you talking about the url to img.x?

Comment: yes the img dosent apear on the apended div and when I check with firebug I get failed to load the given url

Comment: Firebug recognizes `console.log(width);`. If you disable FireBug, FF also freezes. Try commenting console before trying on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

are there multiple divs named "exit" or just the one that you create dynamically... one wouldn't recommend using class selector haphazardly this way.. why not make it as the id and test it... or you could even use `.appendTo(div.exit:first)` to specify the element.. if you have multiple divs with class name exit this could be your problem

Comment: theres just the one i created dinamicly

Answer (score 0):

If you give full path for the URL, image loads in [my fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/M9Hqh/1/). Moreover, image doesn't seen if you give negative values to top and right styles in "div.exit".